Bluetooth connection failed: unable to find service record
After upgrading from Kubuntu 24.04 to 24.10 above error appeared on my another Linux machine when trying to send a file to Kubuntu via Bluetooth in KDE. Also was unable to send file from my phone to Kubuntu via bluetooth. While previously I was able to send a file without any problems.

Solution was found on Ubuntu Forums. I just extended it a bit:
sudo apt-get remove libkf5bluezqt6 libkf5bluezqt-data
sudo apt-get reinstall --purge bluez bluez-obexd bluedevil qml6-module-org-kde-bluezqt libkf6bluezqt6 libkf6bluezqt-data

Not sure where the problem was: in Plasma 5 packages which were orphaned on upgrade or bluez however everithing works fine after the above command and even without restart!

After laptop sleep, awake error happened again, 2nd command solved issue again. So assume some Ubuntu bug.
